# Authentication with Fastify-gql plugin

Tags: javascript, node.js, fastify

Any Example on how to leverage fastify-jwt plugin with fastify-gql for authentication?. I want to protect '/graphql' route but not '/' and '/health' routes.

Any help is appreciated?

Answer (score 0):

I have started a PR with this example.

You can check the source code [here](https://github.com/fastify/example/pull/13/files).

The plugin `fastify-gql` doesn't expose this feature, but it registers the routs you need to protect.
So, listening for the `onRoute` hook, you can check when the `fastify-gql` plugin is adding his routes and append your `preValidation` hook to them and apply your auth logic.